# Yii framework generated forms field types dont corespond to database

Tags: crud, yii

I am using gii to generate CRUD operations for a large number of tables, but the generated form uses a text box for the boolean data types instead of the checkbox

In my table model I modified the rules function to use a boolean validator for my fields

```
public function rules() {
 return array(
  ...
  array('single, random, public', 'boolean'),
  ...
 );
}
```

but the generated form still uses a text box instead of a checkbox, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you found as good an answer as you are going to get over in the Yii forums :) :
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10690-gii-crud-generator-field-type-is-always-text-for-boolean/